# How do I bind one of two different values in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need the data to be one of two possible values, depending on which actually exists. Let's say I have a list of TVs and I want to store that value of the "name" of myTVs[0] and myTVs[1].

E.g.
`var myTVs = [
    {
        "JapaneseTV":
        {
            "name":"Sony"
        },
        "TaiwaneseTV":{}
    },
    {
        "JapaneseTV":{},
        "TaiwaneseTV":
        {
            "name":"Samsung"
        }
    }
];`

Is there a way to bind the data in Angular using the equivalent of:

`<p ng-repeat="tv in myTVs">{{tv.name}}</p>`

where tv.name = JapaneseTV.name || TaiwaneseTV.name; // I.e. I don't have to check which one to use, it just picks the one that returns a value.

Comment: Ah, i worked it out myself. It would be: <p ng-repeat="tv in myTVs">{{myTVs[$index].JapaneseTV.name || myTVs[$index].TaiwaneseTV.name}}</p>. Ridiculously easy. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

It might looks simpler like

```
<p ng-repeat="tv in myTVs">{{tv.JapaneseTV.name || tv.TaiwaneseTV.name}}</p>
```

since you got `tv` in `myTVs`

Comment: Yes, a schoolboy error on my part. Thanks for clearing that up for those who come afterwards. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p ng-repeat="tv in myTVs">{{myTVs[$index].JapaneseTV.name || myTVs[$index].TaiwaneseTV.name}}</p>
```